# Sum Values of dicts from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe containing dictionaries in their cells.
First I filter the columns where there are None values, in order to iterate and explore the ones with dictionaries.
T iterate over the columns with dictionaries and my goal is to sum the values of those dictionaries and add them to a new column pero column explored.

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The dataframe columns are something like this:

```
[In] `df['column_A'].iloc[1]`
[Out] 
{'16875259': 0.0,
 '16909775': 9.0,
 '16909808': 214.0,
 '16909816': 3696.0,
 '16910032': 725.0,
 '16910067': 27.0,
 '16910182': 11.0,
 '16910237': 4.0,
 '16910262': 3191.0,
 '16910358': 52.0,
 '16910411': 73.0,
 '16910416': 111.0,
 '16910477': 1869.0,
 '16910598': 2425
```

## The code I managed to build is somthing like this:

```
for column in my_df:
    if(my_df[column].values[1]!='None' or my_dfdf1[column].values[1] !=None):
        for column in df1:
            for item in df1[column].values:
                for i in item:
                    #print(i)
                    # Here I need to sum the values
```

I expect the sum of the values but I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: [pandas example style for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if-else` statement for sum if values are dictionaries and [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise processing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[{'16875259': 0.0, '16909775': 9.0, '16909808': 214.0},
                        {'16875259': 0.0, '16909775': 10.0}, 
                        np.nan],
                    'b':[{'16875259': 3.0, '16909775': 9.0, '16909808': 214.0},
                         np.nan,
                        {'16875259': 4.0, '16909775': 10.0}, 
                        ]})
print (df)
0  {'16875259': 0.0, '16909775': 9.0, '16909808':...   
1                {'16875259': 0.0, '16909775': 10.0}   
2                                                NaN   

                                                   b  
0  {'16875259': 3.0, '16909775': 9.0, '16909808':...  
1                                                NaN  
2                {'16875259': 4.0, '16909775': 10.0}  

df = df.applymap(lambda x: sum(x.values()) if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
print (df)
       a      b
0  223.0  226.0
1   10.0    NaN
2    NaN   14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following:

```
df['column_A'].apply(lambda x: sum(x.values()))
```